# Event bus in my Android app for standard Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, queue, event-bus

I have several Thread (java.lang.Thread) in my android application to do special treatments all the time. Currently I use some queues (ArrayBlockingQueue) to communicate between these threads, and I would like to simplify this communication by replacing with event bus.

I checked Google Guava event bus for example. Is it ok for my using context ? Or is there another lib to do that ?

Ps: my Android app has no UI, just some threads to do some specific treatments.

Thank you very much guys !

Comment: http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been using this one: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

You just define your event classes and onEvent methods. To me it work fast enough, I go reading rss news and posting them new to the UI lists and progress bars.